# How many coupling constants if my gauge group has many factors?

Tags: gauge-theory, yang-mills

I am reading a review article where $U(1)\times{}SU(2)\times{}SU(3)$ gauge transformations are considered. It says that when such a gauge transformation is done the gauge fields $A^{\alpha}_{\mu}$ transform like this ($\alpha$ is just a label of the different fields)

$A^{\alpha}_{\mu}\to{}A'^{\alpha}_{\mu}+\partial_{\mu}\epsilon^{\alpha}(x)+C_{\alpha\beta\iota}\epsilon^{\beta}(x)A^{\iota}_{\mu}$

where we have

$C_{\alpha\beta\iota}=gf_{\alpha\beta\iota}$

being $g$ the gauge coupling constant. Am I to expect there to be 3 different coupling constants, one for each factor of my gauge group, or do they somehow mix to generate one?

Comment: @JamalS, the two groups are canonically isomorphic, so it doesn't really matter the ordering (and it doesn't really affect the question: how many gauge couplings are there?).

Comment: @silvrfück, could you provide a link to the review article?

Comment: @AlexNelson sure http://www.het.brown.edu/people/danieldf/literary/eric-KKtheories.pdf page 1097. I didn't post the link because the gauge trans are induced by infinitesimal isometries in a compact manifold and I thought (maybe I am wrong) that all that information was irrelevant to the point I am asking

Comment: @silvrfück Thanks. I have a 2 hour bus-ride to work, and a 2-hour bus-ride home...I needed something to read :)

Comment: @AlexNelson XD you are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group $G=U(1) \times SU(2) \times SU(3)$ is decomposed as the product of three simple groups and there is a coupling constant for each simple component of them: $g$, $g'$ and $g_s$.

In the case of the Standard Model, where the symmetry $SU(2)_L\times U(1)_Y$ is spontaneously broken as $SU(2)_L\times U(1)_Y \to U(1)_{em}$, the Weinberg Angle $\theta_W$ is defined by

$$\cos\theta_W=\dfrac{g}{\sqrt{g^2+g'^2}} \qquad \text{and}\qquad \sin\theta_W=\dfrac{g'}{\sqrt{g^2+g'^2}}. $$

and the different gauge couplings are related with the electric charge $e$ by:

$$e=g \sin\theta_W.$$

The only way to have only one coupling constant is to have a simple gauge group. One example is the model proposed by Georgi and Glashow in the 70's to explain the electroweak sector. In this model, the gauge group is $G=SO(3)$ and there is indeed only one coupling constant.

Comment: so, in $C_{\alpha\beta\iota}=gf_{\alpha\beta\iota}$  the structure constants are zero when we consider generators of the different factors, and when we consider generators of each factor we use the corresponding coupling constant?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But remember: matter fields belongs to a representation of $SU(2)$, $U(1)$ and $SU(3)$. So, the transformation laws of the matter fields depend on the coupling constant of all these groups, including the Abelian group $U(1)$.

Comment: Rmk: the only exception is the case where they are singlets (i.e. they are invariante under gauge group transformations).